# Why is this React component rendering infinitely?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-component

I am having an issue with this react component here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import StickyNote from './StickyNote';

function StickyNotes() {

  const [stickyNotes, setStickyNotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Here")
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/notes")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setStickyNotes(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('Error: ', error))
  }, [stickyNotes])
    
  
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center m-5" >
      {stickyNotes.map((note) => <StickyNote title={note.title} body={note.body} id={note.id} key={note.id} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default StickyNotes
```

I am trying to get all of the notes so I am doing a get request to my back end. When I first run my app I notice that my component keeps rendering infinitely. I know that I can pass in an empty array for a dependency and this behavior will stop. The problem is that I need the `useEffect` hook to run every time there is a change to the `stickyNotes` state so that when a user creates a note the screen is updated with the new note. If I pass in an empty array this won't work. I was under the impression that passing in the `stickyNotes` variable into the dependency array would only run `useEffect` when this value changes but it runs even when `stickyNotes` is not being updated. What is causing this to run infinitely?

Comment: Just remove the stickyNote dependency in the useEffect 2nd argument. It must be rendering infinitely due to data changing constantly. Also, research react lifecycle to know more

Comment: The use effect executes every time `stickyNotes` is updated, but `stickyNotes` gets updated in use effect, so...

Answer (score 1):

It is rendering infinitely because `useEffect` has `stickyNotes` as dependency and you are also updating the `stickyNotes` in the `useEffect` callback. So this is making `useEffect` to run infinitely. To fix you can do one thing that make a separate function to get the notes and call that whenever `stickyNotes` changes and call it in `useEffect` also without dependencies.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import StickyNote from './StickyNote';

function StickyNotes() {

  const [stickyNotes, setStickyNotes] = useState([]);
  const getNotes = () =>{
    //call this function whenever you are changing stickyNotes.
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/notes")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setStickyNotes(data))
      .catch(error => console.log('Error: ', error))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, [])
    
  
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center m-5" >
      {stickyNotes.map((note) => <StickyNote title={note.title} body={note.body} id={note.id} key={note.id} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default StickyNotes
```